# What's the best way to make a Bilingual Static Simple HTML Website?

Tags: javascript, html, static, multilingual

sorry if this has been asked too much but no question seemed to fit my situation.

I'm working on my website.
It's just HTML/CSS/JS (so no wordpress or anything like that)
It pretty much has only 4 pages (Home, Apply, Privacy-Policy, and Terms)
I made the website in English, but I also want to have it in Romanian.

I believe having 2 folders for each language would be the best way:

site.com/en
site.com/ro

But what I would like is if people from Romania would automatically get sent to /ro and the rest of the world to /en

I don't plan on doing many updates to the site as soon as it's finished, so I'm thinking using something like i18n might not be necessary (not even sure what that is), but I'm thinking if I use js to generate content it might slow down the loading speed so I'd only use js or php or whatever in order to automatically send users to the preferred language.

How could I do that, and what would actually be the best way to serve a simple, static, pure code website in two languages?

Thanks :)

Comment: `i18n` is just an abbreviation for the long-to-type word `internationalization`.  The `18` comes from the fact that there are 18 letters between the `i` and the `n`.

Answer (score 2):

With `navigator.language` you can get the browser language. I would prefer that setting rather than going via location. 
Say you're Romanian but on holiday in Germany, you would still get the romanian version of the site.

You could set the english version as default and then use javascript to redirect to your romanian version if you detect romanian language code.

Comment: Well currently your website already works in English. You could add a script like this on top:
`if (navigator.language === "ro_RO") window.location.replace("site.com/ro)

And in the romanian version you would directly link to the other romanian pages.
Or you use a subdomain like ro.site.com then you can just link to "/home" and the links are the same everywhere.

Comment: okay, I've decided not to do the automatic switch as I don't think it's that necessary. Instead I'm thinking of adding a flag somewhere that would take me to the Romanian version. For that do I need anything else besides a simple <a> tag?

Comment: That's a good solution too. I don't think you have to do anything else, what you wouldn't do on any other website - Setting different Meta Information, HTML language tag, etc.